# Nothing happens after Facebook login requests is authenticated

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to login Android app through Facebook.

After clicking the Facebook login button, a new web view opens where it asks for permission, I press `OK` and then it got close and application is already closed, hence nothing.

```
public class Splash extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(android.R.id.content,mainFragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }


public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String TAG = "FBLoginFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper mUiHelper;
    private OnFBAccessTokenPass mTokenPasser;
    private String mSessionToken;


    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            mSessionToken = session.getAccessToken();
            // Request user data and show the results
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // pass the access token to the activity
                        // with the user id
                        mTokenPasser.onFBAccessTokenPass(mSessionToken, user.getId());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            mSessionToken = "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        //mTokenPasser = (OnFBAccessTokenPass) a;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        mUiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        mUiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mUiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mUiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public interface OnFBAccessTokenPass {
        public void onFBAccessTokenPass(String accessToken, String uid);
    }
}
```

`In Manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Comment: did you check if your onActivityResult method get called after you press the ok button and the dialog dismiss?

Comment: yes, i have a breakpoint set over `onActivityResult` but it never get hits.

Comment: I think your callback has to be in your Activity, not your Fragment.

Comment: which function should i move to activity?

Comment: I believe your callback function and your UiLifecycleHelper should be in the activity, which is where the onActivityResult is. So, everything dealing with Facebook should be in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that main activity gets the result. So override the main's activity onActivityResult to allow the fragment to get the result add this to your main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and change the position of  authButton.setFragment(this); just before the return view;

Comment: Done trying, no help. still same issue. does the application has to close before going to Facebook for authentication? or it should be open in background?

Comment: check if the onActivityResult of your FragmentActivity is called and tell me

Comment: yes, just added the manifest part in question also, please check.

Comment: yeas, that is there too.

Comment: please check out this one here. i am using this and its working if you face any problem please let me know. http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example